# Value of the double integral of $\int_0^1\int_1^3 (4x^3-27x^2y^2)dydx$

Tags: integration

$$\int_0^1\int_1^3\left(4x^3-27x^2y^2\right)dy\,dx$$

$$\int_0^1\left(4x^3y-9x^2y^3\right)\Big|_1^3\,dx$$

$$\int_0^1\left(12x^3-243x^2-4x^3+9x^2\right)dx$$

$$\int_0^1\left(8x^3-234x^2\right)dx$$

$$\left(2x^4-78x^3\right)\Big|_0^1$$

Of course this gives a negative answer and is supposedly wrong, but I don't see any problem with my work. I know for a fact that when you take the derivative with respect to $y$, you will get $4x^3y-9x^2y^3$, and I know for a fact that when you plug in $3$ you will get $3^3$ which is $27$ and multiply that by $9$ and you get $243$! These supposed arithmetic errors are killing me! I don't even see any in this problem.

Comment: What is the region and the function?

Comment: You're solving the integral correctly, [W|A confirms it as well](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Int%5BInt%5B4x%5E3-27x%5E2y%5E2,y,1,3%5D,x,0,1%5D). If that's not the right answer, perhaps the problem is in setting up the integral.

Comment: To stop banging your head against your wall, you might want to compute the double integral the other way round, that is, integrating first with respect to $x$ then with respect to $y$. That is, start with $\int_0^1(4x^3-27x^2y^2)dx=\left.x^4-9x^3y^2\right|_0^1=1-9y^2$ hence your double integral is $\int_1^3(1-9y^2)dy=\left.y-3y^3\right|_1^3=3-3\cdot3^3-1+3=-76$. This does not *prove* your first computation is correct but this definitely suggests that it might be so...

Comment: Are we supposed to be integrating over the rectangle bound by the $y$-axis and the lines $x=1$, $y=1$, and $y=3$? If not, then I'm afraid you've set up the integral incorrectly.

Answer (score 1):

As the commenters said, you've evaluated the integral correctly. Every tool I use to check it confirms that the answer is $-76$. If that's not the answer you were looking for, you must have set up the integral incorrectly.